# How can I create a new number in an Array in a Specific position?

Tags: c#

I am trying to save random numbers in an array

I have tried this bot it gives me an error (A constant value is expected Code CS0150)

`

```
int x = 0;

Random rnd = new Random();
int[] cards;
while (x != 5)
{
    cards =new int[x] { rnd.Next() };
    Console.WriteLine(cards[x]);
    x++;
}
```

`

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. You need to provide the error message in your post if you get one. Actually the message is quite informative if you read it carefully. Your main problem is that you create the array each time new inside the loop. you need to create it once outside the loop. and the second is what your error is telling you, that you can either specify the amount of initialize it. if the numbers don't fit you get an error

Comment: Currently you're creating a new array on ever iteration. I assume you want `cards[x]  = rnd.Next()` within the loop, and `int[] cards = new int[5]` directly *before* the loop.

Comment: but do I have to define the amount of cards I want?

Comment: yes, at least for an array. If you want something dynamic, use a `List<int>` instead. However as of your code you're just adding 5 values, so I'm not sure if you need that.

Comment: shouldn't your update be an answer? Or does it cause new errors?

Answer (score 1):

Currently you're creating a new array on every iteration. I assume you want `cards[x]  = rnd.Next()` within the loop, and `int[] cards = new int[5]` directly *before* the loop:

```
int x = 0;

Random rnd = new Random();
int[] cards = new int[5];
while (x != 5)
{
    cards[x] = rnd.Next();
    Console.WriteLine(cards[x]);
    x++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a List instead of an Array so I can use an undefined number of cards
`

```
int x = 0;

Random rnd = new Random();
List<int> cards = new List<int>();
while (x != 5)
{
    cards.Add(rnd.Next()); 
    Console.WriteLine(cards[x]);
    x++;
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

**--- Not for Points ---**

If you're going to use a `List<>`, then use the `Count` property:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
List<int> cards = new List<int>();
while (cards.Count < 5)
{
    cards.Add(rnd.Next());
    Console.WriteLine(cards[cards.Count-1]);
}
```

If you're going to use an `Array`, then use a `for` loop and the `Length` property:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int[] cards = new int[5];
for(int x=0; x<cards.Length; x++)
{
    cards[x] = rnd.Next();
    Console.WriteLine(cards[x]);
}
```